# Can a docker image be deployed on a different operating system?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62488742/are-there-different-images-for-different-os-on-docker-hub), but I would like to confirm this further by relating my question to also private repositories rather than public ones only in Docker Hub.

Assuming that Docker has been installed on both the source and destination machines, which of the following is true?

1. The source and destination machines must have the same OS, OS distribution, and OS version.
2. The source and destination machines must have the same OS and OS distributions, but the OS versions can be different.
3. The source and destination machines must have the same OS, but the OS distributions and OS versions can be different.
4. Ths source and destination machines can have different OSs, OS distributions, OS versions always.
5. The source and destination machines can have different OSs sometimes.

By a different OS I am referring to using two different operating systems among Windows, Linux, and Mac.

Comment: The basic requirement is "the target environment must run a reasonably recent version of Linux". Docker under Mac and Windows typically runs inside a Linux VM, and the Linux distribution on the Docker host doesn't matter directly (what really matters is the kernel version, but even then, in the vast majority of cases, that doesn't matter all that much either).

Comment: @Iarsks I guess we can say option 4 is generally true then. Now I see why Docker has been so popular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is: Your system must use a recent version of Docker or close version from one host to another, and have a similar or close Kernel version, by using MacOS up to date, docker windows up to date and a linux distribution in LTS you should be pretty sure that your container is working on all your hosts